# Macro that copies a row

Tags: excel, vba

I found a macro that almost does what I need.  It copies a row named "Totals" and pastes the row in a new sheet.  The row "Totals" have formulas and I need values.  How do I adjust the macro to work correctly?

Here is the macro code:

```
Sub RowCopy2()
Dim rngFind As Range

With Worksheets("Hol. Stats").UsedRange
Set rngFind = .Find("Totals", _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=True)
End With
rngFind.EntireRow.Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
Sub RowCopy2() Dim rngFind As Range
  With Worksheets("Hol. Stats").UsedRange 
    Set rngFind = .Find("Totals", _
         LookIn:=xlValues, _
         LookAt:=xlWhole, _
         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
         SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
         MatchCase:=True) 
  End With 

  rngFind.EntireRow.Copy 
  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: @J. Miller: You can accept an answer and that will signal that your question was answered.  There should be a little checkmark next to the answers for you to click on.

Answer (score 1):

It is worthwhile making use of the range object to test if the search string is actually found, you could then take alternative action, provide info to the user etc

And fwiw you can bypass copy and paste by setting the values of the destination to the values of the source.

```
Sub RowCopy2()
Dim rngFind As Range
Set rngFind = Worksheets("Hol. Stats").UsedRange.Find("Totals", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(1).Value = rngFind.EntireRow.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quicker to find the row "Totals" using the rows range name. You can then do it in two lines...

```
Rows(Range("Totals").Row).Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

That's the reason for using range names in Visual Basic. Other properties of ranges are covered in the text for this [Excel help video](http://www.excel4business.com/videos/vba-ranges-rows-columns.php)

Comment: Ed, #1 why is that "quicker" that find - both are two lines if the range exist and both will be executed immediately #2 There is academic evidence that range names lead to more errors in financial models, see http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1009/1009.2765.pdf

Comment: I meant it was quicker to type/doesn't require any variables to be defined within VBA

Comment: (Took too long editing!) Quicker to type/much easier to remember without recording a macro or performing a web search/doesn't require any variables to be defined within VBA

In terms of range names leading to errors...the research in question was with respect to formulas...VBA is further removed from the average user and the assumption becomes "if it stops working correctly, no-one will notice and, even if they do, it won't get corrected". Therefore you have to choose a method for referring to spreadsheet locations that will be least badly affected by users moving rows/columns etc.